# Código PHP en sentencia SELECT de SQL para traer solo información de variable $_SESSION['login_user']

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, session

cuento con un archivo .php en el cual estoy mostrando la tabla clientes, quisiera saber como mostrar únicamente los registros de la tabla correspondientes al usuario logueado, almacenado en $_SESSION['login_user']";

```
>                         <thead>
>                           <tr>
>                             <!-- <th>Id</th> -->
>                             <th>Documento</th>
>                             <th>Primer nombre</th>    >                           
>                             <th>Primer apellido</th>    >                             
>                           </tr>
>                         </thead>    >                         
>                         <tbody>
>                           <?php
>                           include('../controllers/conectardb.php');
>                           
>                           $query5 = "select * from cliente ";
>                           $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query5) or die(mysqli_error());
>                           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
>                             $DNI = $row['DNI'];
>                             ?>
>                             <tr>
>                               <td><?php echo $row['DNI']; ?></td>
>                               <td><?php echo $row['nombre1']; ?></td>
>                               <td><?php echo $row['apellido1']; ?></td>
>                               </td>
>                             </tr>
>                           <?php } ?>
>                         </tbody>
>                       </table>
```

Nota: en la tabla **clientes**, existe el campo **usuario** en el cual se indica que usuario realizó cada registro.

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Si te entiendo bien lo que tratas es traer unos registros donde ya fueron almacenados con el id del usuario y quieres consultarlos con el mismo usuario?

Comment: @JohnySalazar la consulta la tengo de manera general, trae todos los registros de la tabla clientes (select * from clientes), quisiera saber como indicar que consulte los registros donde el campo usuario de la tabla clientes corresponda al usuario logueado, algo así como (select * from where usuario = $_SESSION['login_user']).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la variable de sesión que guardas al iniciar sesión, puedes consultar a la BD

```
$iduser = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$query5 = "select * from cliente where usuario = '$iduser' ";
```

Para esto necesitas:

- Tener un campo identificador único en la tabla usuario
- Al iniciar sesión, guardar en un variable sesión ese identificado
- Con el WHERE consultas solo a ese usuario que inició sesión

Comment: Apliqué lo propuesto y funcionó, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que $_SESSION['login_user'] contiene el id del usuario que insertas en clientes solo agregalo a la consulta concatenado:

```
 $query5 = "select * from cliente where usuario ='".$_SESSION['login_user']."'";
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar. $_SESSION['login_user'] contiene el nombre de usuario logueado, ahora bien, al momento de implementar lo sugerido me aparece el siguiente mensaje:Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in

Comment: edite la respuesta para concatenar de otra manera, a ver si asi te toma el parametro, y otra cosa no veo donde tienes declarado $conn para la conexion a la base de datos, talvez este en tu archivo conectardb.php asegurate de que este bien declarado